# Pass multiple values inside find_package in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have defined a variable in CMakeLists.txt as follows:

`set(MY_PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES boost-core boost-optional sqlite3)`

I want to check if there are found using `find_package()` as follows:

`find_package(MY_PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES REQUIRED)`.

But this does not work. Any workaround for the same?

Edit: As drescherjm suggested using a foreach loop works perfectly. Here is the code snippet:

```
macro(find_packages)
  foreach(package ${ARGN})
    find_package(${package} REQUIRED)
  endforeach()
endmacro()
```

Call it using:

````
find_packages(${MY_PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES})```
````

Comment: You could use a loop: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html)

Comment: For Boost, use the included standard [Boost package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html).

Comment: Using a foreach loop sounds like a good workaround. FindBoost seems like a lot of work for now.

Comment: For header-only libraries (like Boost optional) it's four added lines: One `find_package()` line, one `if` to see if it was found, one to add the Boost header file directory, and an `endif`. You could basically copy-paste the example shown in the link into your own `CMakeLists.txt` file, modifying only the minimum version number.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the suggestion. Will look into it. For now I've solved it using a macro. I've posted the solution in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is `MY_PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES` is a list, 
and you tried to use `find_package` on those list, but `find_package` is expecting `PackageName` separately

so your workaround is to call `find_package` for every packages (using loops on the those list) and define this in the `macro` for easy using.